# Openlayers 3 - Multilinestring Zoom-in/out flashing layer

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3, multilinestring

I'm trying to plot two linestring (WKT) on openlayers 3.

When zoom (in or out) the layers are flashing and some times show or hide.

Do some one know what is going on?

Thanks

The code is:

```
var rasterLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({ source: new ol.source.MapQuest({ layer: "osm" }) });
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: vectorSource });
var wktFormat = new ol.format.WKT();
var layers = [rasterLayer, vectorLayer];

var olMap = new ol.Map({
        layers: layers,
        target: "map",
        view: new ol.View({ center: ol.proj.transform([-47.4556640445469, -23.5087675969813], "EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857"), zoom: 15 })
    });

var wkt = "MULTILINESTRING ((-47.4556640445469 -23.5087675969813, -47.455663222553 -23.508781331245),(-47.4597839082327 -23.5090240050454, -47.4597690420473 -23.5090246913242))";
var feature = wktFormat.readFeature(wkt);
feature.getGeometry().transform("EPSG:4326", "EPSG:3857");
feature.setStyle(new ol.style.Style({ stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({ color: "red", width: 9 }) }));
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lz1t8jpn/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Solved at https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/5511

Thanks Andreas and Openlayers Team!!!